# Having issues installing a react project

Tags: reactjs, npm, project

> ```
> yarn add v1.22.4
> [1/4] Resolving packages...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
> error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80".
> info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "D:\\React\\resort\\yarn-error.log".
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
>
> Aborting installation.
>  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts cra-template --cwd D:\React\resort has failed.
>
> Deleting generated file... package.json
> Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
> Done.
> ```

Can you please help me figure out what's happening while I try to install?

Comment: Hi, this is problem most likely with your internet connection. The connection is unstable...

Comment: my internet connection is stable :)

Comment: Ok, then try this... do you have `npm` installed? I'll assume so, therefore go on and delete the `yarn.lock` file. Then just go back to the terminal and run `npm install`. (In other words, try installing the project using `npm` instead). I must admit i've had the same "internet warnings" from `yarn` (sometimes) even when i had a stable connection..:)

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, according to [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5599) discussion, there is a problem with yarn proxy. Someone resolved by doing:

```
$ yarn config set proxy http://username:password@host:port
$ yarn config set https-proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

but I see that this solution does not works for all.
Possible solution: try this way suggested on discussion or use `npm`:

```
npm i react
```